# why I can't add int type value to an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree, treenode

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;


public class TreeNode {
     int val;
     TreeNode left;
     TreeNode right;
     TreeNode(int x){val=x;}
}

public class SortedArrayToBalancedBST {

  public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] nums) {
        if(nums.length==0) return null;
        else return sortedArrayToBST(nums, 0, nums.length-1);
    }
    public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] nums, int left, int right){
        ArrayList<TreeNode> list = New ArrayList<TreeNode>()
        TreeNode root =null;
        int mid=(right+left)/2;
        if(right>=left){
            root= new TreeNode(nums[mid]);
            root.left=sortedArrayToBST(nums, left, mid-1);
            root.right=sortedArrayToBST(nums, mid+1, right);
            list.add(root);
            //System.out.print(list);
        }
        if(left>right) return null;
        return root;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nums[]= {1,3,5,7,9};
        SortedArrayToBalancedBST s = new SortedArrayToBalancedBST();
        s.sortedArrayToBST(nums);
        System.out.print(s.toString())
    }
```

I would like create a balanced tree by using the code above. But java return me an error that told me:Cannot invoke add(TreeNode) on the array type int[], so what should I do, why I can't add int type value to an array? And also I wish the output looks like [5,3,7,1,null,null,9] if I'm right.

Comment: You can't add an object of type TreeNode to an array of integer. It needs to be `TreeNode[] arr = new TreeNode[5]` and you insert the object into array by providing an index like `arr[0] = new TreeNode(5)`

Comment: [Java: Appending to an array](https://programming.guide/java/array-append.html)

Comment: Your constructor is taking int as and argument, `TreeNode(int x){val=x;}` whereas you are initializing it with an array `root= new TreeNode(nums[mid])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array type doesn't have an `add(...)` method. You must specify the index to which you are replacing the element (i.e. `arr[0] = 1;`). Also, if your array will contain null values, consider using `Integer[]` type instead of the primitive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, It's already a recursive method so I don't know how to assign index for these values. The reason I tried to create an array is that when I use system.out.print(root), then the program return me results like that:TreeNode@15db9742TreeNode@6d06d69cTreeNode@7852e922TreeNode@4e25154fTreeNode@70dea4eTreeNode@15db9742TreeNode@6d06d69cTreeNode@7852e922TreeNode@4e25154fTreeNode@70dea4e

Comment: In that case, use ArrayList instead of an array. And if you want to print contents of an object, you must override the `toString()` method of your `TreeNode` class to return the stuff that you want to print. Otherwise, it will just print random hashcode values

Comment: Hi sir, are you still there. Now i'm using list to store my values and it's good, but how to override toString method. I was searching on the google for roughly one hour but didn't find any example that related to mine. I do remember had using toString() function on the leetcode practices but I really don't know how to build a toString method by myself.

Comment: In your `TreeNode` class, add the function: `@Override public String toString() { return String.valueOf(val); }` if you only want to print the value of the TreeNode. Otherwise, format it to include the left and right node values.

Comment: Still have an error and it said cannot convert from int to string. then I add this: @Override public int toString() { return val; }, it said return type is imcompatible with object.toString()

Comment: Yea my bad. I edited my original comment to correct the function